# how to shorten filter function with replace and split?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, replace, split

I'm using a filter function in combination with replace() and split(). it looks like this

```
jQuery('table .abc').filter((i, el) => jQuery(el).text(jQuery(el).text().replace('a', 'b').split(' ')[0] + ' ' + jQuery(el).text().replace('a', 'b').split(' ')[1]))
```

Is there a way to shorten it so I don't have to use the same replace and split function twice? because I just need to combine [0] and [1].

Comment: Off-topic: Looks like you're using `.filter()` incorrectly and should be `.each()`.  And you don't need `.each` either as you can use do `$(select).text(function(i, text) { return text.replace...` [.text](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

Answer (score 0):

To shorten your code

```
jQuery('table .abc').filter((i, el) => 
    jQuery(el).text(jQuery(el).text().replace('a', 'b').split(' ')[0] 
                    + ' ' 
                    + jQuery(el).text().replace('a', 'b').split(' ')[1]))
```

you can use the [overload](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) for `.text()` which takes a function and calls that function for each element in the selection (which is what you're doing, but more succinct).

As it looks like you're taking just the first two words, you could also use `.slice(0,1)` giving:

```
$("table .abc").text((i,txt) => txt.replace("a","b").split(" ").slice(0, 2).join(" ") );
```

Working example:

```js
$("table .abc").text((i, txt) => txt.replace("a", "b").split(" ").slice(0, 2).join(" "));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='abc'>This is more than two words</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='abc'>Here is a second line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='abc'>OneWord</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```